# Obtain rooftop geocode address accuracy

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the best way to obtain rooftop geocode address accuracy
for an address in egypt.

My objective is to get the best point location (latitude, longitude) within 10 meters deviation from address produced by geocode process.

I see building numbers on egypt map, but when I try to include this number in geocode request, it gives me wrong location point.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to extract the geocode information from an IP address or is your problem with the gmaps API?

When looking at the maps in Egypt it seems to me that the numbers are not part of the street information but are rather added by contributors as details for each representation of a building. That's why when you call an address by streetnumber you will not get a precise location.